# Get value from input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here I have:

```
 var row = table.getSelection()[0].row;
console.log(data.getValue(row,0));
 console.log((data.getValue(row,0)).val());
```

and I get:

```
<input class="span2 form-control" id="pocetak1" size="16" type="text" value="2013-04-01" readonly>

Uncaught TypeError: Object <input class="span2 form-control" id="pocetak1" size="16" type="text" value="2013-04-01" readonly> has no method 'val'
```

How I can get `value` from `data.getValue(row,0)` ???

Answer (score 3):

`val` is part of the jQuery API. The native element only exposes `.value`. Using `.value` on an input element in javascript will give you its value.